# Swap out a layer of a container image

Tags: docker, containers

I am wondering if it is possible to swap out a layer of a container image for another.  Here is my scenario:

I have a docker file that does the following:

1. It pulls the .net core 3.1 debian slim (buster) image
2. Builds the source code of my application and adds it as a layer on top of the .net core image

When a new version of the .net core 3.1 runtime image comes out, I would like to make a new image that has that new version, but has the same application layer on top of it.

I do NOT want to have to find the exact version of the code I used to build the application and re-build.

The idea is to replicate upgrading the machine and runtime, but not have any alteration to the application (less to test with the upgrade).

**Is there a docker command that I can use to swap out a layer of an image?**

Comment: This is pretty unconventional and there are a whole slough of ambiguous technical issues that would need to be solved to _properly_ do this. I do not think there is an existing `docker` command to do this, nor is there any tool designed for this purpose. Furthermore, I do not recommend that you do this. **However**, I will humor your question - _technically_, it is possible. I am developing a proof-of-concept tool that is able to swap base images (which is what you have described) for you. I will post it in an answer soon, but it may take a few days due to the complex nature of it.

Comment: @concision - My Company currently runs our custom software on Virtual Machines.  An autobuild creates the custom software and then it is deployed to that virtual machine.  When a patch or upgrade is needed on the virtual machine, we don't recompile the code, we just upgrade the virtual machine (maybe even making a new virtual machine and installing the exe onto it.)  I am looking for a way to recreate this scenario using containers.  (Where I can upgrade the operating system, without making a new build of my code.)  How is this normally done with containers?

Comment: Containers are meant to be ephemeral - they should hold their persistent state in volumes or another means of persistent storage that is not inside the container's state (i.e. filesystem). If all persistent data is outside of the container's internal state, then rebuilding the base Docker image and creating a new updated container with the same volumes on persistent data is how you "upgrade" the OS. The analogy of VMs does not quite work here, Docker works on an entirely different architecture with a union layer filesystem where top layers are dependent on the bottom layers.

Comment: Furthermore, while I cannot stress enough that you should rebuild from sources, it is technically possible by editing the image directly. However, if you are trying to "upgrade" a running container's OS, you will need to stop the container. Since this is an interesting unorthodox concept, I am spending some time trying to accomplish this by writing a CLI tool. However, in order to accomplish this you need have the separately have the original base image, the new base image, and the application image you wish to "upgrade". Do you know/have those for your image you wish to "upgrade"?

Comment: @concision - I not looking to perform surgery on a running container.  I want to modify the container image.  I am fine to stop a running container and swap it out for the new image.  What I don't want is to build from code again.  We have a culture that when you re-build from code, then we have to re-test because we cannot be sure that the exact right code was all used.  So, I would have, for example, the Debian Slim image for .Net Core 3.1, and on that I have built my app code.  I would like to take that image, and swap out an older .NetCore 3.1 image for a new one, without rebuilding code.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying the requirements further. Give me a few days, and I should be able to implement a CLI tool for this scenario. There are several caveats (which I will detail later), but I suspect for a simple .net app image it should work. I have to implement an efficient image reader/writer in the tool, which is what will take a significant amount of the development time.

Comment: „*…I want to modify the container image…*“ – @Vaccano — I'm relatively new to Docker. The very first thing I learned is that [*Docker images are immutable by design*](https://www.google.com/search?q=docker+images+are+immutable). — „*…We have a culture that when you re-build from code, then we have to re-test because we cannot be sure that the exact right code was all used…*“ — That sounds like a culture that is *risk averse*. Hacking the Docker technology to do something it isn't designed to do is the polar opposite of being risk averse. What you're wanting to do could be done with CI and VCS.

Comment: @Vaccano That could be a silly question but, can't you hold binaries on machine running docker, with [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) attached to the container? In that case swapping base image would be done with two commands, docker container rm ... and docker container run (with required paramteres).

Comment: @Vaccano As promised in my previous comments, I implemented a CLI tool that accomplishes what you are after. Take a look at the second section of my answer. I am doubtful you will find any official `docker` command that enables you to do this.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is broken into two distinct sections:

- **Part I: Build From Sources Instead**: Explains why this idea should not be done.
- **Part II: A Proof-of-concept Implemented CLI Tool**: A CLI tool I implemented specifically for this question, with a demonstration.

The first section can be skipped if potentially adverse side effects are not a concern.

---

## Part I: Build From Sources Instead

**No**, there is probably not a `docker` command for this - and likely never will, due to a whole slough of technical issues. Even by design, this is not meant to be trivially possible; images and layers are meant to be immutable after being built. It is strongly recommended that the application image is instead rebuilt from the original sources, but with a new base image by modifying the `FROM` command.

**There are *numerous* consistency issues that make this idea ill-advised**, of which a few are listed below:

- Certain `Dockerfile` commands do not actually create a layer, they update the final layer's internal manifest and the image's manifest. Commands that state `Removing intermediate container XXXXXXXXXXXX` are actually updating these aforementioned manifests, and *not* creating new layers. This requires *correctly* updating the only relevant changes when swapping from the old base image to the new base image; e.g. reconciling changes from `ENV`/`LABEL`/`MAINTAINER`/`EXPOSE`/`CMD`/`ENTRYPOINT` commands.
- `ENV` commands that alter the application image's configuration from variables inherited in the previous base image may not be updated correctly. For example, in the application image, there might be the following command `ENV` command:

  ```
  ENV PATH="/path:${PATH}"
  ```

  If the application image's old base image layers are swapped out, and the new base image contains a different `${PATH}` variable, it is ambiguous how to reconcile the differences without a manual decision by a developer.
- If `apt`/`apt-get`/`apk`/`yum` is used to install Linux packages, these packages are installed in the application image as subsequent layers. The installed packages are not guaranteed to be compatible with the new base image if the underlying OS or executables change in the new base image layers.

## Part II: A Proof-of-concept Implemented CLI Tool

"Upgrading" an image's base is *technically* possible by doing direct manipulation on the image archive of the already-built Docker application image. However, I cannot reiterate this enough - **you should *not* even be attempting to edit the bottom layers of an existing image**. <sub><sup><sub>Seriously - stop it, get some help. I am 90% sure this is a war crime.</sub></sup></sub>

For the sake of humoring this question thoroughly though, **I have developed a proof-of-concept CLI tool written in Java over on my GitHub project [concision/docker-base-image-swapper](https://github.com/concision/docker-base-image-swapper)** that is designed to swap *base images* (but not arbitrary layers). The design choices I made to resolve various consistency issues are a "best guess" on what action should be taken.

Included is a demonstration for swapping the base image for an already-built Java application image from JDK8 to JDK11, implemented in the [`demo/demo.sh`](https://github.com/concision/docker-base-image-swapper/blob/master/demo/demo.sh) script. All core code is ran in isolated Docker contains, so only Bash and Docker are necessary dependencies on the host to run this demonstration. The demo application image is only built once on JDK 8, but is run twice - once on the original JDK 8 image, and another time on a swapped-base JDK 11 image.

If you experience some technical difficulty with the tool, I may potentially be able to fix the issue. This project was quickly hacked together and has pretty poor code quality; furthermore, it likely suffers from various unaccounted edge cases. I might thoroughly rewrite this in Rust within the next month or two with a focus on maintainability and handling all edge cases.

> ***Warning***: I *still* do not advise trying to edit images; the use of the tool is at your own risk.

### The Concept

There are three images relevant in this process, all of which are *already-built* (i.e. no original sources are needed):

- **application image**: the application image that is currently based off of the old base image, but needs to be swapped to a newer base image.
- **old base image**: the older base image that the application image is based off using a `FROM` command in the original `Dockerfile`.
- **new base image**: the newer base image that should replace the application image's layers inherited solely from the `FROM old-base-image` layers.

By knowing which layers and configurations of the application image are inherited from the old base image, they can be replaced with the layers and configurations from the new base image. All image layers and manifests can be obtained as a tar archive by using the `docker save` command. With an archive(s) of all relevant three images, a tool can analyze the differences between

---

## Warnings on Alternatives

Beware of doing simply a `COPY --from=...` from the old application image, as the original application's image configuration (through commands such as `CMD`, `ENTRYPOINT`, `ENV`, `EXPOSE`, `LABEL`, `USER`, `VOLUME`, `WORKDIR`) will not be properly replicated.

Answer (score 2):

Two tools that provide this type of functionality that I have found are listed below.

1. Crane rebase https://github.com/google/go-containerregistry/blob/main/cmd/crane/rebase.md#using-crane-rebase
2. Buildpack (rebase) https://buildpacks.io/docs/concepts/operations/rebase/

[image]

NOTE: You do have to watch that you don't have items that need updates in higher layers.  And that higher layers do NOT have updates in them that would conflict with the new base.  Example using image below the base is a TOMCAT container.  If layer 4 of the original container did a update tomcat package that would overshadow the update of same files on the NEW BASE.  Which could result in a non functional system.  So as always your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible? Yes. But it's rarely done because of how error prone it is. For example, if the previous build would have created a library, but the library already exists in the original base image, that library won't be included in the first build. If the base image removes that library, then the resulting merged image will be missing that library since it's not in the new base layers and isn't in the old application layer.

There are a few ways I can think of to do this.

Option 1: If you know the specific files in one image, then use the `COPY --from` syntax to copy those files between images. This is the least error prone method, but requires that you know every file you want to include. The resulting Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM new_base

# if every file is in /usr/local/bin:
COPY --from=old_image /usr/local/bin/ /usr/local/bin/
```

Option 2: you can export the images and create your own new image by combining the layers between the two. For this, there's `docker save` and `docker load`. That would look like:

```
docker save old_image >old_image.tar
docker save new_base >new_base.tar
mkdir old_image new_base new_image
tar -xvf old_image.tar -C old_image
tar -xvf new_base.tar -C new_base
cp old_image/*.json new_image/
# manually: copy each layer directory you want to save from old_image, you can view the nested tar files to find the proper ones
# manually: copy each layer directory from new_base into new_image
# manually: modify the new_image/manifest.json to have the new tag for your image, and adjust the layer references
tar -cvf new_image.tar -C new_image .
docker load <new_image.tar
```

Option 3: this could be done directly to the registry with API calls. You would pull the old manifest, adjust it with the new layers, and then push any new layers and then the new manifest. This would require a fair bit of coding (see [regclient/regclient](https://github.com/regclient/regclient/) for how I've implemented some of these API's in Go).

Option 4: I know I've seen a tool that does this in a specific scenario but the name of it escapes me. I believe it required that you use their base images that were curated to reduce the risk of incompatibilities between versions, and limited what base images could be swapped, so I don't think it was a general purpose tool.

Note that option 2 and 3 both require either manual steps or for you to write some code if you want to automate it. Because of how error prone this is (as described above) I don't think you'll find anyone maintaining and supporting a tool to implement it. The vast majority rebuild from a Dockerfile using a CI tool.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a small utility script using Python which lets you append a tarball to an existing container image in a container registry (without having to pull existing image data), available at https://github.com/malthe/appendlayer.

The following illustrates how it works:

```
[ base layer ]                    => image1
[ base layer ] [ appended layer ] => image2
```

The script supports any registry that implements the [OCI Distribution Spec](https://github.com/opencontainers/distribution-spec).